# Confusion with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to learn C. The reading I've been doing explains pointers as such:

```
/* declare */
int *i;

/* assign */
i = &something;

/* or assign like this */
*i = 5;
```

Which I understand to mean `i` = the address of the thing stored in `something`

Or

Put 5, or an internal representation of 5, into the address that *i points to.

However in practice I am seeing:

```
i = 5;
```

Should that not cause a mismatch of types?

Edit: Semi-colons. Ruby habits..

Comment: Since you're learning C, it might be worth learning that every statement has to end with a semicolon.

Comment: Check your vision. When `i` is of type `int*` all you should see with `i = 5;` are compiler errors. What you likely see are variables with automatic storage duration like `int i`.

Comment: Re. semi-colons. Coming from ruby... habit.

Comment: @pmr I am speaking of, for example, the tutorial to connect to postgresql [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/accessing-postgresql-cc). Both conn and res are declared `*con` and `*res` but assigned in the fashion I questioned above.

Comment: @procidence except that res=PQexec(...)  and the PQexec function probably returns a pointer, not a typical variable.

Comment: Yeah, http://doxygen.postgresql.org/libpq-fe_8h.html it returns a PGresults pointer. PGresults being a struct.

Comment: @Philip Ahh, yes. I hadn't considered returning a pointer. For some reason I was thinking pointers could not be returned; rather that making changes to the thing pointed to is *roughly* equivalent to returning something in that it is accessible to the caller. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand to mean i = the address of the thing stored in something

Actually i contains an address, which SHOULD be the address of a variable containing an int.
I said should because you can't be sure of that in C:

```
char x;
int *i;
i = (int *)&x;
```

if i is a pointer, than assign to it something different to a valid address accessible from you program, is an error an I think could lead to undefined behavior:

```
int *i;
i = 5;
*i; //undefined behavior..probably segfault
```

here's some examples:

```
int var;
int *ptr_to_var;

var = 5;
ptr_to_var = var;

printf("var %d ptr_to_var %d\n", var, *ptr_to_var); //both print 5
printf("value of ptr_to_var %p must be equal to pointed variable var %p \n" , ptr_to_var, &var);
```

Comment: So doing `i = 5;` puts the address of `5` into `i`? Is this any different from doing `i = &5`?

Comment: no. it puts five into i. In other words put a number that doesn't represent a valid address inside a pointer that is supposed to store an address.

Comment: @Heisenbug: just to play Devil's Advocate, the value five *could* be a valid address on some imaginary system, no?  Or is there something in some C/POSIX/etc. spec that defines valid memory address ranges?

Comment: What about an integer starting at 4? The second byte is at adress 5. Memory is adressed per-byte, not per-integer.

Comment: @Femaref: well, I said a wrong thing. I'll remove that comment.

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes, in your example setting an int pointer to 5 is a mismatch of types, but this is C, so there's nothing stopping you. This will probably cause faults. Some real hackery could be expecting some relevant data at the absolute address of 5, but you should never do that.

The English equivalents:

```
i = &something
```

Assign i equal to the address of something

```
*i =5
```

Assign what i is pointing to, to 5.

Answer (score 2):

If you set `i = 5` as you wrote in your question, `i` would contain the address 0x00000005, which probably points to garbage.

Hope this helps explain things:

```
int *i;           /* declare 'i' as a pointer to an integer */
int something;    /* declare an integer, and set it to 42 */
something = 42;   
i = &something;   /* now this contains the address of 'something' */
*i = 5;           /* change the value, of the int that 'i' points to, to 5 */
                  /* Oh, and 'something' now contains 5 rather than 42 */
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're seeing something along the lines of

```
int *i;
...
i = 5;
```

then somebody is attempting to assign the address `0x00000005` to `i`.  This *is* allowed, although somewhat dangerous ([N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)):

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
> ...
> 3 An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
> `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*.<sup>55)</sup> If a null pointer constant is converted to a
> pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.
> ...
> 5  An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
> result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
> entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.<sup>56)</sup>
> ...
> 55) The macro `NULL` is defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.17.
>
> 56) The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment.

Depending on the architecture and environment you're working in, `0x00000005` may not be a valid integer address (most architectures I'm familiar with require multibyte types to start with even addresses) and such a low address may not be directly accessible by your code (I don't do embedded work, so take that with a grain of salt).

Comment: This is a really helpful explanation, thanks. It seems C allows you to do whatever you want, including murder your computer! I'll have to be careful.

Comment: It's not *quite* that bad, but yes, C was designed to offer as much flexibility with as little fuss as possible.  As such, it assumes that you know what you're doing at all times.  More often than not, that's not a valid assumption, even among people who've been writing C for several decades (such as myself).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

This declares a variable name "myIntPointer" which has type "pointer to an int".

```
int *myIntPointer;
```

This takes the address of an int variable named "blammy" and stores it in the int pointer named "myIntPointer".

```
int blammy;
int *myIntPointer;

myIntPointer = &blammy;
```

This takes an integer value 5 and stores it in the space in memory that is addressed by the int variable named "blammy" by assigning the value through an int pointer named "myIntPointer".

```
int blammy;
int *myIntPointer;

myIntPointer = &blammy;

*myIntPointer = 5;
```

This sets the int pointer named "myIntPointer" to point to memory address 5.

```
int *myIntPointer;

myIntPointer = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

assignment of hard-coded addresses, is something that shouldn't be done (even in the embedded world, however there are some cases where it's suitable.)
when declaring a pointer, limit yourself to only assign a value to it with dynamiclly allocated memory(see malloc()) or with the & (the address) of a static (not temporary) variable. this will ensure rebust code, and less chance to get the famous segmentation fault.

good luck with learning c.